# Google Forms output in Sheets combined with formula skips a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

So I have found the answer sort of already a couple of times, but not for my specific formula. I have a Google Form with checkboxes, but when multiple are checked the (long) answers are in CSV format.

I am using the formula:

```
=substitute('Form responses 1'!I2,",",char(10))
```

But when a new answer is inputted it goes from I2 to I4 while the output is in I3. I found both INDIRECT and ARRAYFORMULA as answers. But I cannot make my formula work correctly in the sheet.

Any help is appreciated. I tried for so long.

Comment: could you please format your code as code? code is formatted [as such](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in row 1:

```
={"header"; INDEX(SUBSTITUTE('Form responses 1'!I2:I, ",", CHAR(10)))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is working! I just had to change one thing:

```
={"AM"; INDEX(SUBSTITUTE('Form responses 1'!C2:C101, ",", CHAR(10)))}
```

I had to put an max to the cells. Thanks a lot!